# Selecting a RadioButton in a ToggleGroup whenever it is navigated to with the arrow keys

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I have a program with a series of `RadioButton`s that share a `ToggleGroup`. The following is a simplified version:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton();
        button1.setText("Button 1");
        button1.setOnAction(this::printSelectedRadioButton);
        button1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton();
        button2.setText("Button 2");
        button2.setOnAction(this::printSelectedRadioButton);
        button2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void printSelectedRadioButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) actionEvent.getSource();
        System.out.println(radioButton.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: The stage generated by the above code]

When I click on a `RadioButton`, an `ActionEvent` is fired and the `printSelectedRadioButton()` method is called. However, once I have clicked on a `RadioButton`, if I navigate to the other one using the arrow keys, the `ActionEvent` is not fired and the method is not called. I want navigating to a particular button to have the same effect as clicking on it. How would I do this?

Comment: @Slaw do you have a native (preferably windows) example of a toggle _firing_ on selection? from a gut feeling, I would say, the basic behavior implemented in fx is quite correct. Client  code can always enhance to do more (keeping in mind the triggering an action is a strong measure)

Comment: selection != action: add a normal button before the group (to have it initially focused) that selects a toggle -> no fire. The other way round: note that behavior after a mouse click is two step (pressed -> arm, released -> fire-if-armed). To see, press a toggle, then move off before release - no fire.

Comment: @Slaw but that's how it is since ages (old awt and swing, fi :) Consider a keyboard-only interaction: to reach a particular control, while navigating, we'll touch (and potentially select, depends on where we started and whether or not any toggle in the group had been selected) several toggles - do we really want to trigger the action for each (that we just navigated through because it was on the way to our real target)? Don't think so, there should be something on top. The usual keyboard gesture for triggering an action on a button is space (or enter) when focused.

Comment: @kleopatra Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadioButton#setOnAction works only on click. If you want to get selected radio button you have to add ***ChangeListener*** to ToggleGroup.

```
    ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
    toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldToggle, newToggle) -> {
        if (toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
            System.out.println("selected radio button: " + toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle());
        }
    });
```